# How to share mysql connection between http goroutines?

Tags: go

I'm a Go noob and can't find any complete examples of opening a mysql connection in Go and then sharing it among http handlers. Here is my code so far, how would I use the db connection that I opened in main() in my HomeHandler?

```
package main

import (
  "database/sql"
  "fmt"
  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {

  fmt.Println("starting up")

  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/mydb?charset=utf8")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error opening database: %v", err)
  }

  db.SetMaxIdleConns(100)

  r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)

  http.Handle("/", r)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  fmt.Fprintf(w, "home")

}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The database/sql package manages the connection pooling automatically for you.

`sql.Open(..)` returns a handle which **represents a connection pool**, not a single connection. The database/sql package automatically opens a new connection if all connections in the pool are busy.

Applied to your code this means, that you just need to share the db-handle and use it in the HTTP handlers:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var db *sql.DB // global variable to share it between main and the HTTP handler

func main() {
    fmt.Println("starting up")

    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root@unix(/tmp/mysql.sock)/mydb") // this does not really open a new connection
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error on initializing database connection: %s", err.Error())
    }

    db.SetMaxIdleConns(100)

    err = db.Ping() // This DOES open a connection if necessary. This makes sure the database is accessible
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error on opening database connection: %s", err.Error())
    }

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)

    http.Handle("/", r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var msg string
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT msg FROM hello WHERE page=?", "home").Scan(&msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Database Error!")
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Julien, thanks for answering. Couldn't expect a better source than the author of the Go-MySQL-Driver! It seems there might be a typo in the code as I get a compile error: `./main.go:18: cannot assign *sql.DB to db (type sql.DB) in multiple assignment`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the type now.
@fmt.Println.MKO that this doesn't work is still not true. The database/sql is designed exactly for concurrent use cases like this.

Comment: FYI, here are a few more simple examples how to access a DB in HTTP handlers:
https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/go/src/hello/hello.go

Comment: Thanks Julien! It works perfectly. Nice work on the driver btw - I remember watching Go climb in the framework benchmarks over the last few rounds which led me to start learning Go because of the raw speed.

Comment: Does exactly this code above panic? If yes, what is the panic reason?
I'm pretty sure you have an error somewhere in your code. This is the conventional way to access databases in Go.

Comment: yes, i know this, i gave hm this answer hours ago, just because of panic i removed it, then found solution over channel, now i found solution also with the var, look at my answer, and yes here is the panic: 2013/06/29 23:17:28 http: panic serving [::1]:58548: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 4 [running]:
net/http.func·007()
 /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1022 +0xac
sync/atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32()
 /usr/local/go/src/pkg/sync/atomic/asm_amd64.s:14 +0xd
sync.(*Mutex).Lock(0x20)
 /usr/local/go/src/pkg/sync/mutex.go:43 +0x35

Comment: for some reason var db, is nil inside the handle method, if you assign return value to a buffer and then buffer to db, it works

Comment: Sounds a lot like the beloved `:=` shadowning. Let me guess you have `db, err := sql.Open` in your code? This uses a local db var instead of the global one.

Comment: @JulienSchmidt isn't it required to close the db connections?.

Comment: @AnuruddhaPremalal it isn't. sql.DB is the abstraction of a database pool. If connections are not used anymore or timeout, they are removed from the pool / closed.