# Dumping MySQL tables to JSON with Golang

Tags: mysql, go

Was putting together a quick dumper for MySQL to JSON in Go.  However I find that everything that I retrieve from the database is a `[]byte` array.  Thus instead of native JSON integers or booleans, I'm getting everything encoded as strings.

Subset of the code:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)


func dumpTable(w io.Writer, table) {
    // ...

    rows, err := Query(db, fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s", table))
    checkError(err)
    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    checkError(err)

    scanArgs := make([]interface{}, len(columns))
    values   := make([]interface{}, len(columns))

    for i := range values {
        scanArgs[i] = &values[i]
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(scanArgs...)
        checkError(err)

        record := make(map[string]interface{})

        for i, col := range values {
            if col != nil {
                fmt.Printf("\n%s: type= %s\n", columns[i], reflect.TypeOf(col))

                switch t := col.(type) {
                default:
                    fmt.Printf("Unexpected type %T\n", t)
                case bool:
                    fmt.Printf("bool\n")
                    record[columns[i]] = col.(bool)
                case int:
                    fmt.Printf("int\n")
                    record[columns[i]] = col.(int)
                case int64:
                    fmt.Printf("int64\n")
                    record[columns[i]] = col.(int64)
                case float64:
                    fmt.Printf("float64\n")
                    record[columns[i]] = col.(float64)
                case string:
                    fmt.Printf("string\n")
                    record[columns[i]] = col.(string)
                case []byte:   // -- all cases go HERE!
                    fmt.Printf("[]byte\n")
                    record[columns[i]] = string(col.([]byte))
                case time.Time:
                    // record[columns[i]] = col.(string)
                }
            }
        }

        s, _ := json.Marshal(record)
        w.Write(s)
        io.WriteString(w, "\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: what output are you trying to create? That would be helpful in understanding what you're asking for. When I hear "dumping mysql" I think of `show tables` and `describe tablex`, but I'm not sure if that's what you're wanting.

Comment: The ```SELECT * FROM %s", table``` statement - thus the contents of the table

Comment: I don't know how to get the result set without specifying the types of the columns. I'll retract my answer since it didn't satisfy the question.

Comment: @rexposadas Was really hoping that you figured it out.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I also needed to dump database tables to json and here is how I achieved: 
(different than another answer in this topic, everything is not string, thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17885636/4124416, I could get integer fields correctly)

```
func getJSON(sqlString string) (string, error) {
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlString)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    count := len(columns)
    tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    values := make([]interface{}, count)
    valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)
    for rows.Next() {
        for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
          valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
        }
        rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)
        entry := make(map[string]interface{})
        for i, col := range columns {
            var v interface{}
            val := values[i]
            b, ok := val.([]byte)
            if ok {
                v = string(b)
            } else {
                v = val
            }
            entry[col] = v
        }
        tableData = append(tableData, entry)
    }
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(tableData)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    fmt.Println(string(jsonData))
    return string(jsonData), nil 
}
```

Here is a sample output:

```
[{"ID":0,"Text":"Zero"},{"ID":1,"Text":"One"},{"ID":2,"Text":"Two"}]
```

Comment: Absolutely agree with you, on my code there are error handlings. But deleted while copying here to focus on logic...

Comment: turkenh: I understand; personally for any example I prefer to at least have an `if … {return err}` or if in a main-like context `if … { log.Fatal(err) }`. The problem is a lot of programmers are incompetent and will just blindly copy-n-paste code without any clue and then follow the "pattern". So the `foo, _ := errorReturningFunc` mis-use spreads :(.

Comment: I got your concerns, updated the code accordingly and will definitely take this into account next time. Thanks...

Comment: Anyone tried this in go 1.4.2 or higher?. I'm getting all the fields in string type.

Comment: At present I am getting `integer` fields as strings. I think there is an issue in the ConvertValue function. I'm going to dig in tonight and see what I can learn.  https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/527bcd55aab2e53314f1a150922560174b493034/statement.go#L123-L150

Comment: Thank you for this code - I've been searching for hours how to get the result set into a proper JSON array.

Answer (score 3):

It is needed to use prepared statements to get the native types. MySQL has two protocols, one transmits everything as text, the other as the "real" type. And that binary protocol is only used when you use prepared statements. See https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/407

The function getJSON below is correct:

```
func getJSON(sqlString string) (string, error) {
  stmt, err := db.Prepare(sqlString)
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }
  defer stmt.Close()

  rows, err := stmt.Query()
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }
  defer rows.Close()

  columns, err := rows.Columns()
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }

  tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)

  count := len(columns)
  values := make([]interface{}, count)
  scanArgs := make([]interface{}, count)
  for i := range values {
    scanArgs[i] = &values[i]
  }

  for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(scanArgs...)
    if err != nil {
      return "", err
    }

    entry := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i, col := range columns {
      v := values[i]

      b, ok := v.([]byte)
      if (ok) {
        entry[col] = string(b)
      } else {
        entry[col] = v
      }
    }

    tableData = append(tableData, entry)
  }

  jsonData, err := json.Marshal(tableData)
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }

  return string(jsonData), nil 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's not much you can do because the `driver` - `database/sql` interaction is pretty much a one way street and the driver can't help you with anything when the data is handed over to `database/sql`.

You could try your luck with http://godoc.org/github.com/arnehormann/sqlinternals/mysqlinternals

- Query the database
- Retrieve the Column slice with `cols, err := mysqlinternals.Columns(rows)`
- Create a new var `values := make([]interface{}, len(cols))` and iterate over `cols`
- Get the closest matching Go type per column with `refType, err := cols[i].ReflectGoType()`
- Create type placeholders with `values[i] = reflect.Zero(refType).Interface()`
- `rows.Next()` and `err = rows.Scan(values...)`. Don't recreate `values`, copy and reuse it.

I guess this will still be pretty slow, but you should be able to get somewhere with it.
If you encounter problems, please file an issue - I'll get to it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

I have a table named users inside practice_db database. I have mentioned the table structure with data in the following program that converts the users table into JSON format.

You can also check the source code at https://gist.github.com/hygull/1725442b0f121a5fc17b28e04796714d.

```
/**
    {
        "created_on": "26 may 2017",
        "todos": [
            "go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql",
            "postman(optional)",
            "browser(optional)",    
        ],
        "aim": "Reading fname column into []string(slice of strings)"
    }
*/


/* 
    mysql> select * from users;
    +----+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | id | fname     | lname    | uname    | email                         | contact      | profile_pic                                                                                     |
    +----+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | Rishikesh | Agrawani | hygull   | rishikesh0014051992@gmail.com | 917353787704 | https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/user_group_users_accounts_contacts-512.png |
    |  2 | Sandeep   | E        | sandeep  | sandeepeswar8@gmail.com       | 919739040038 | https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eldorado-user/40/user-512.png                            |
    |  3 | Darshan   | Sidar    | darshan  | sidardarshan@gmail.com        | 917996917565 | https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/child_boy-512.png                          |
    |  4 | Surendra  | Prajapat | surendra | surendrakgadwal@gmail.com     | 918385894407 | https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/account_male-512.png                       |
    |  5 | Mukesh    | Jakhar   | mukesh   | mjakhar.kjakhar@gmail.com     | 919772254140 | https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/male-circle-512.png                        |
    +----+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> 
*/

package main

import "log"
import "net/http"
import "encoding/json"

import (
    _"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"   
    "database/sql"
)

func users(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "<username>:<password>@tcp(127.0.0.1:<port>)/<dbname>?charset=utf8" )
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "hygull:admin@67@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/practice_db?charset=utf8")

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("select id, fname, lname, uname, email, contact, profile_pic from users")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    type User struct {
        Id int       `json:"id"`
        Fname string `json:"firstname"`
        Lname string `json:"lastname"`
        Uname string `json:"username"`
        Email string `json:"email"`
        Contact int `json:"contact"`
        ProfilePic string `json:"profile_pic"`
    }

    var users []User

    for rows.Next() {
        var id, contact int
        var fname string
        var lname string
        var uname, email, profile_pic string

        rows.Scan(&id ,&fname, &lname, &uname, &email, &contact, &profile_pic)
        users = append(users, User{id, fname, lname, uname, email, contact, &profile_pic })
    }

    usersBytes, _ := json.Marshal(&users)

    w.Write(usersBytes)
    db.Close()
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/users/", users)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

/* REQUSET

   http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/
*/

/* RESPONSE
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "Rishikesh",
    "lastname": "Agrawani",
    "username": "hygull",
    "email": "rishikesh0014051992@gmail.com",
    "contact": 917353787704,
    "profile_pic": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/user_group_users_accounts_contacts-512.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstname": "Sandeep",
    "lastname": "E",
    "username": "sandeep",
    "email": "sandeepeswar8@gmail.com",
    "contact": 919739040038,
    "profile_pic": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eldorado-user/40/user-512.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstname": "Darshan",
    "lastname": "Sidar",
    "username": "darshan",
    "email": "sidardarshan@gmail.com",
    "contact": 917996917565,
    "profile_pic": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/child_boy-512.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstname": "Surendra",
    "lastname": "Prajapat",
    "username": "surendra",
    "email": "surendrakgadwal@gmail.com",
    "contact": 918385894407,
    "profile_pic": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/account_male-512.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "firstname": "Mukesh",
    "lastname": "Jakhar",
    "username": "mukesh",
    "email": "mjakhar.kjakhar@gmail.com",
    "contact": 919772254140,
    "profile_pic": "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/male-circle-512.png"
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I am trying to do this but same code(+ my db structure) is not working for me. When I am trying to show json in web page its showing empty json is [{},{},{},{}][91 123 125 44 123 125 44 123 125 44 123 125 93]. how can i solve this. how can i see the json in web page in json format?

Comment: I can see two two lists consecutively. That is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers here, this is the most efficient code I could come up with. Note that this is outputting each row as a separate JSON array to save key name repetition.

```
// OutputJSONMysqlRowsStream outputs rows as a JSON array stream to save ram & output size due to key name repetition
func OutputJSONMysqlRowsStream(writer http.ResponseWriter, rows *sql.Rows) {

    defer rows.Close()

    columns, err := rows.Columns()

    if err != nil {
        OutputJSONError(writer, "Failed to get column names")
        return
    }

    jsonColumns, err := json.Marshal(columns)

    if err != nil {
        OutputJSONError(writer, "Failed to encode json of column names")
        return
    }

    writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/cal-json-stream; charset=utf-8")

    fmt.Fprintln(writer, "{\"status\": \"done\", \"data\":{ \"json_stream_fields\":"+string(jsonColumns)+"}}")

    columnCount := len(columns)
    rowDataHolder := make([]interface{}, columnCount)
    rowDataHolderPointers := make([]interface{}, columnCount)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {

        for i := 0; i < columnCount; i++ {
            rowDataHolderPointers[i] = &rowDataHolder[i]
        }

        err := rows.Scan(rowDataHolderPointers...)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        } else {

            for i, value := range rowDataHolder {
                tempValue, ok := value.([]byte)

                if ok {
                    rowDataHolder[i] = string(tempValue)
                }
            }

            jsonEncoder := json.NewEncoder(writer)
            err = jsonEncoder.Encode(rowDataHolder)

            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can dump the table into json just fine, however everything will be string :(

```
q := "select * from table"
debug("SQL: %s", q)

rows, err := db.Query(q)
checkError(err)
defer rows.Close()

columns, err := rows.Columns()
checkError(err)

scanArgs := make([]interface{}, len(columns))
values := make([]interface{}, len(columns))

for i := range values {
    scanArgs[i] = &values[i]
}

for rows.Next() {
    err = rows.Scan(scanArgs...)
    checkError(err)

    record := make(map[string]interface{})

    for i, col := range values {
        if col != nil {
            record[columns[i]] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", string(col.([]byte)))
        }
    }

    s, _ := json.Marshal(record)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)
}
```