# Having trouble getting a string out of my pgx query using row_to_json in sql in golang

Tags: postgresql, go

Is there a way to get back a string from a pgx query if you use row_to_json etc. to format the returned rows as json text?

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rows, err := DB.Query("select row_to_json(rows) as data from (select * from userinfo) rows;")

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(rows)
}
```

Comment: It is always good to support your question with code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what I did. I ended up using `QueryRow` instead of `Query` because I'm only expecting one json result. I then use `row.Scan()` to get the result into a string and then `w.Write([]byte(result))` to write the resulting string to the response.

If you have multiple rows in your result, you might need to handle the result differently. [Possibly this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991541/dumping-mysql-tables-to-json-with-golang)?

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var result string
    err := postgresConn.QueryRow(`My SQL Query`).Scan(&result)
    switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        log.Printf("No user with that ID.")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write([]byte("{}"))
    case err != nil:
        log.Println(err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    default:
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write([]byte(result))
    }
}
```